# findByPrimary is not a function

Tags: javascript, sqlite, sequelize.js, discord, discord.js

## TL;DR

### I am getting an error saying that findByPrimary is not a function when using Sequelize.

I have been following [this tutorial](https://discordjs.guide/sequelize/currency.html#file-overview) on how to make a currency system for a Discord bot using Sequelize and SQLite 3. However, whenever I use `findByPrimary` on a model I get the following error:

```
(node:9182) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Users.findByPrimary is not a function
```

`Users` is defined in `models/Users.js`:

```js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    return sequelize.define('users', {
        userId: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        balance: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            defaultValue: 0,
            allowNull: false
        }
    }, {
        timestamps: false
    });
};
```

which is referred to in `dbObjects.js`:

```js
//modules
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

//sequelize connection info
const sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password', {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'sqlite',
    logging: false,
    storage: 'database.sqlite'
});

//models
const Users = sequelize.import('models/Users');

//export
module.exports = {Users};
```

which is imported in `server.js` and used as one of the arguments in `execute` in a command file:

```js
const {Users} = require('./dbObjects');

//command is a file (in this case commands/inventory.js and commands/buy.js)
command.execute(message, Users);
```

which is used in the commands that don't work:
`commands/inventory.js`

```js
module.exports = {
    execute: async (message, Users) => {
        const target = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;
        const user = await Users.findByPrimary(target.id);
    }
};
```

`commands/buy.js`

```js
module.exports = {
    execute: async (message, Users) => {
        const user = await Users.findByPrimary(message.author.id);
    }
};
```

I have tried using `findById` but that results in the same error message. I also have tried adding the following code to the execute function in the command files:

```js
const Sequelize = require('sequelize);
const SQLite = require('sqlite3');
```

The only difference between my code and the aforementioned tutorial's is that I am using a [command handler](https://discordjs.guide/command-handling).

All other Sequelize functions such as `findAll` have been working.

Comment: I believe it's [`findByPk()`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-findByPk)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please Use **findByPk** instead of  **findByPrimary**
See sequelize documents : http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/models-usage.html

```
Users.findByPk(id)
```